# How to elegantly return to text file after executing a `:terminal` command similar to `:!`?

Tags: neovim, terminal

I want to return to the open file after I executed command with `:terminal <command>`

First off, I am using `neovim`.

So to get to the situation, I want to improve: follow these  steps :

1. create a sample file with  `nvim foo`
2. write some text, e.g. `hello you`  and save `:w`
3. in vim command mode, run `:terminal cat foo`

Currently, what happens? I can see how the terminal returns my output `hello you`.

My question is, how do I return to my file `foo`?

When I type `:q` I quit vim. Then  I could run `:e foo`, but I prefer a more elegant solution. Since when I run `:! cat foo` I get

```
:! cat foo
Hello you

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So that a simple `enter` returns me to my file. Is there a similar way to do this with `:terminal`

*Remark*
I prefer `:terminal` since it has the terminal colors which help in reading longer test results. Surely, I am using the `cat` command just as an example.

## update

After some digging in the documentation [link](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html). I found that the terminal has its own mapping so that I can change the `esc` key to get into command mode with

```
:tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>
```

I assumed that just adding `:!q` like `:tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>:!q` would quit but that does not work.

But when using `:tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>` in the command I type `:!q` I get

```
E37: No write since last change
E162: No write since last change for buffer "[No Name]"
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

That means I only need to add force stop into shortcut
Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: Why not just move to the previous split with `<c-w>p`? Maybe I don't fully understand your question... but do you really need to close the terminal window?

Comment: Any of C-w c or C-w w or C-w p would do… also see `:help windows` and `:help terminal` for details on using `:terminal`

Comment: I'd recommend keeping the terminal window open, and move between windows with `<c-w> h/j/k/l` or similar commands. Otherwise, you can close the terminal window with `<c-\><c-n>:q!` (notice it's `:q!` instead of `:!q`), or better, with `<c-w><c-c>`.

Comment: @husB I tried `:tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>:q!` and it did not close on <kbd>esc<\kbd>. Well I just want to reproduce the behaviour of from `:terminal <cmd>`  similar to ` `:! <cmd>`

Comment: You need to terminate the command with `<cr>`, ie. `:tnoremap <Esc> <C-\><C-n>:q!<cr>` 
. Otherwise use `<c-w><c-c>`. It's much neater too ---  `:tnoremap <Esc> <C-w><C-c>`.

Comment: Don’t map escape. You’ll be in for some pain

Answer (score 0):

If terminal process has already finished then Vim/Neovim is back in Normal mode. So you can do absolutely anything that is available in Normal mode for buffer switching. For example, `:h ctrl-^`. More info for beginners can be found in `:h user-manual`, specifically, the section "Editing more than one file" in `:h usr_07.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `:shortmess=a` option or try
`:silent !cat foo`